# Настройка размера метки на разных зумах (еще раз)

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Приветствую!
Задаю вместо метки текст с помощью iconContent. Использую созданный мною пресет с iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent' и другими атрибутами. Меток много - текст разный. Вопрос, как уменьшать размер такой метки при уменьшении зума? Хочу добиться эффекта подписей зданий как у обычных я.карт.

С помощью данного примера (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/scalable_placemarks) создается еще один iconLayout. Напомню, что у меня уже используется стандартный iconLayout и использование второго невозможно (или я чего-то не знаю?). Да и разница в том, что в примере все метки одинаково выглядят, а у меня, во-первых, текст, во-вторых, он НА ВСЕХ МЕТКАХ РАЗНЫЙ!
Как мне связать два лэйаута или что мне делать в данной ситуации? Может я вовсе неправильно все сделала?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Привет, идея примера в том чтобы при построении лейаута подписаться на событие изменения зума карты и при его срабатывании пересчитывать размер метки.

Логику подписки на событие можно сделать где угодно, даже в отдельной функции. Вот пример с двумя разными лейаутами (метками):

```
var initChip = function (calculateSize, className) {
    var map = this.getData().geoObject.getMap();
  if (!this.inited) {
    this.inited = true;
    // Получим текущий уровень зума.
    var zoom = map.getZoom();
    // Подпишемся на событие изменения области просмотра карты.
    map.events.add('boundschange', function () {
      // Запустим перестраивание макета при изменении уровня зума.
      var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
      if (currentZoom != zoom) {
        zoom = currentZoom;
        this.rebuild();
      }
    }, this);
  }
  var options = this.getData().options,
      // Получим размер метки в зависимости от уровня зума.
      size = calculateSize(map.getZoom()),
      element = this.getParentElement().getElementsByClassName(className)[0],
      // По умолчанию при задании своего HTML макета фигура активной области не задается,
      // и её нужно задать самостоятельно.
      // Создадим фигуру активной области "Круг".
      circleShape = {type: 'Circle', coordinates: [0, 0], radius: size / 2};
  // Зададим высоту и ширину метки.
  element.style.width = element.style.height = size + 'px';
  // Зададим смещение.
  element.style.marginLeft = element.style.marginTop = -size / 2 + 'px';
  // Зададим фигуру активной области.
  options.set('shape', circleShape);
}

var createChipsLayout = function (calculateSize) {
// Создадим макет метки.
    var Chips = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
        '<div class="placemark"></div>',
        {
            build: function () {
                Chips.superclass.build.call(this);
                initChip.call(this, calculateSize, 'placemark');
            }
        }
    );

    return Chips;
};

var createChipsLayout2 = function (calculateSize) {
// Создадим макет метки.
    var Chips = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
        '<div class="placemark-2"></div>',
        {
            build: function () {
                Chips.superclass.build.call(this);
                initChip.call(this, calculateSize, 'placemark-2');
            }
        }
    );

    return Chips;
};


ymaps.ready(function () {
    var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.755249, 37.617437],
        zoom: 4
    });

    map.geoObjects.add(new ymaps.Placemark([55.755249, 36.317437], {
        balloonContent: 'Линейная зависимость размера метки от уровня зума',
        hintContent: 'Линейная зависимость'
    }, {
        iconLayout: createChipsLayout(function (zoom) {
            // Минимальный размер метки будет 8px, а максимальный мы ограничивать не будем.
            // Размер метки будет расти с линейной зависимостью от уровня зума.
            return 4 * zoom + 8;
        })
    }));

    map.geoObjects.add(new ymaps.Placemark([55.755249, 37.617437], {
        balloonContent: 'Квадратичная зависимость размера метки от уровня зума',
        hintContent: 'Квадратичная зависимость'
    }, {
        iconLayout: createChipsLayout2(function (zoom) {
            // Минимальный размер метки будет 8px, а максимальный 200px.
            // Размер метки будет расти с квадратичной зависимостью от уровня зума.
            return Math.min(Math.pow(zoom, 2) + 8, 200);
        })
    }));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jxryjsh9/11/

В вашем случае я советую вам сделать параметры у лейаута с помощью которых вы будете настраивать его внешний вид и содержание, а логику подписки оставить как в первоначальном примере. Но можно пойти и путем выноса функции инициализации (который я описал выше) и созданием множества лейаутов.